# Ruby TCP/IP Client Threading

Tags: ruby, multithreading, tcp, client

I'm using ruby socket for a simple ping-pong scenario.
(The client is sending a string to the server, and the server is sending the string back - that's all)

Simple Client:

```
socket = TCPSocket.new "localhost", 5555
socket.write "test-string\n"
puts socket.gets.inspect
```

It's working fine, until Threads come into play:

```
socket = TCPSocket.new "localhost", 5555
threads = []

5.times do |t|
  threads << Thread.new(t) do |th|

    socket.write "#{t}\n"

    puts "THREAD: #{t} --> [ #{socket.recv(1024).inspect} ]"

  end
end

threads.each { |th| th.join }

# Output: THREAD: 3 --> [ "0\r\n1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n" ]
```

The problem here is that each Thread seems to "listen" for responses from the server with socket.gets, and as a result an arbitrary Thread will receive ALL responses from the server, as you can see from the output.
Preferably each Thread should receive it's own response, the output should not look like

```
THREAD: 3 --> [ "0\r\n1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4\r\n" ]
```

but rather like:

```
THREAD: 0 --> [ "0\r\n" ]
THREAD: 1 --> [ "1\r\n" ]
THREAD: 2 --> [ "2\r\n" ]
THREAD: 3 --> [ "3\r\n" ]
THREAD: 4 --> [ "4\r\n" ]
```

What is the deal here?

Comment: It sounds like you're using threads but not expecting concurrency, so the question is why use threads?

Comment: No that's a misconception. I need the concurrency but all data is getting returned to a single thread instead of it's relative thread.

Answer (score 0):

All your threads are sharing the same socket. You write your messages to the socket and then all 5 threads are sitting waiting for data to be available to read.

Depending on the behaviour of the other end, the buffering in the network stack etc. that could come back in one chunk or multiple chunks. In your particular set of circumstances the data appears in one chunk and one thread happens to get lucky.

To get the behaviour you want you should use one socket per thread.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I will consider that.

Are there maybe other solutions that would fit better in first place?
Maybe TCP/IP is not the best choice to communicate between two LOCAL processes. For example I can think of a system connection limit that could cause problems once a huge number of threads (and in turn sockets and connections) is reached.